# Pointer into vector, but not into a valarray?

Tags: c++, pointers, valarray

I'm trying to extract a const pointer to part way through an array.  I found it works fine when using a vector, but won't compile (VS 2008) when using a valarray.  Can somebody explain what the problem is?

```
struct vector_test
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    const int *pointy(const int i) const
    {
        return &(v[i]); // Ok
    }
};

struct valarray_test
{
    std::valarray<int> v;

    const int *pointy(const int i) const
    {
        return &(v[i]); // error C2102: '&' requires l-value
    }
};
```

Comment: Both usages are violations of the vector or valarray ecapsulation.

Comment: @Charles Peng: the first one is technically ok. Vectors explicitely guarantee contiguous storage for compatibility with C-style arrays. Also, the standard defines exactly (a) that the vector's iterator maybe implemented as the pointer to the element type (b) when a vector's iterators are invalidated (e.g. at resizing)

Comment: @sehe: Thanks for your comment. I know that the first usage is OK. But what I want to say is that it violates the purpose of encapsulation.

Comment: Ok. I get your point. I would agree, but it should be noted that it depends on what you use the vector for, in the end. You can use it as modular container, or just as an 'dynamic array shell' with stack semantics. The standard does support both usage scenarios explicitly.

Comment: @Charles Peng: Unfortunately many code like BLAS/LAPACK does not support valarray. They only support pointers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::valarray<T>::operator [](std::size_t)` returns a `T&`, which will work fine.

`std::valarray<T>::operator [](std::size_t) const` returns a `T`, which will be an rvalue and consequently cannot have its address taken.

Because `valarray_test::pointy` is itself `const`, `valarray_test::v` is treated as `const` and consequently the `const` overload of `operator[]` is called. Either make `valarray_test::v` `mutable` or make `valarray_test::pointy` non-`const`.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is it assumed that a `valarray` is only going to be used for simple types which can be efficiently returned as a copy?  Is there a good reason why `valarray` couldn't have been designed to return a reference?

Comment: "*Is it assumed that a `valarray` is only going to be used for simple types which can be efficiently returned as a copy?*" Yes indeed. "*Is there a good reason why `valarray` couldn't have been designed to return a reference?*" Not with modern compilers, but it may have been a provable optimization at the time `valarray` was originally designed (`valarray` was explicitly designed for balls-out efficiency).

Comment: More importantly: _The `valarray` classes are defined to be free of certain forms of aliasing, thus allowing operations on these classes to be optimized._ (quoted from the C++ standard draft N3485, 26.6.1/2)